# Pub/Sub message triggered from Google Cloud Run hosted application is taking a long time

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a simple Spring boot application hosted in Google Cloud Run which publishes a Google Pub/Sub message to a topic in the same project.

This is taking a long time for about 5 min roughly. Below is the code that I use to publish the Google Pub/Sub message. But the same was working fine with no delay in App Engine environment.

```java
ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
            ApiFutures.addCallback(messageIdFuture, new ApiFutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                    if (throwable instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = ((ApiException) throwable);
                        // details on the API exception
                        log.error("APIException Status Code: {}", apiException.getStatusCode().getCode());
                        log.error("APIException is Retryable: {}", apiException.isRetryable());
                    }
                    log.error("Error publishing message: {}", pubSubMsg);
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
                    log.info("Success msg after publish: {}", messageId);
                }
            }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

How can I overcome this delay in publishing the Pub/Sub message?

Comment: When you are handling a request in Cloud Run, you want to publish a message in PubSub, correct? And it takes 5 minutes to publish it, right? Can you share more of your code? I would like to see if you wait the ApiFuture or if you let it running in background.

Comment: That is the full code i use for publishing pubsub message. I'm using docker to containerize and deploy into cloud run

Comment: What call this code? you should have a function around. I would like to understand the context of the call to this piece of code

Comment: Cloud run severely throttles CPU and since the Java Publisher uses a background thread, it gets blocked until there is another request that wakes up the instance; if you redeploy your cloud run instance with the `--no-cpu-throttling` option you will see better results; caution: this might increase the cost of your service

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Spring Boot creates a JAR file that contains nested JARs. In Cloud Run, these files get unpacked during startup, and this can impact on the run time.

Google App Engine is a managed service; you have no control over the run time, whereas, Cloud Run containers need to be tweaked to optimise the environment.

Based on this, I expect you will need to optimise how your app runs in the container. Are you using a Multi-Stage Build? You can also try using a [Jib plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib) to containerise your application and see if that improves your timings.

I am not overly familiar with Spring Boot, but this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2018/11/08/spring-boot-in-a-container) discusses how to containerise your code for best performance. These links have some useful information on [Jib Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/using-jib-to-containerize-java-apps) configuration, jib extensions on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions) and this [blog post](https://phauer.com/2019/no-fat-jar-in-docker-image/).

Comment: I'm currently using docker file to containerize and deploy into cloud run. I'll try JIB plugin also. But does that cause issue?

Comment: From the documentation it mentions that a fat Spring Boot JAR is "unsuitable for containerization.". GAE is a managed service so you have no control over the run time, whereas, Cloud Run containers need to be tweaked to optimise the environment (size is important). This might not resolve everything!! but try these links for more information: [Jib Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/using-jib-to-containerize-java-apps), [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions), [blog post](https://phauer.com/2019/no-fat-jar-in-docker-image/)

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. I'll check these links.